# How to compare items in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, compare

This is my list

```
my_list = [18, 19, 20, 27, 28, 29, 38, 39, 40]
```

My goal is to sort or create new lists like these

```
list1 = [18, 19, 20]
list2 = [27, 28, 29]
list3 = [38, 39, 40]
```

And then compare each of them and only leave items which are equal like that ,

```
list1 x == list2 x - 10 or list1 x == list3 x - 10
list1 x == list2 x + 10 or list1 x == list3 x + 10
list2 x == list1 x - 10 or list2 x == list3 x - 10
list2 x == list1 x + 10 or list2 x == list2 x + 10
list3 x == list1 x - 10 or list3 x == list2 x - 10
list3 x == list1 x + 10 or list3 x == list2 x + 10
```

So the final list will be like

```
final = [18,19,28,29,38,39]
```

I have wrote those codes but can't achieve the goal. Those were just unsuccessful attempts.

N1

```
for lst in my_list:
    ind = my_list.index(lst)
    if int(my_list[ind]) == any(int(x)-10 for x in my_list) or int(my_list[ind]) == any(int(x)+10 for x in my_list):
        print(ind)
```

N2

```
for id in my_list:
    ind = my_list.index(id)
    try:
        if id == (my_list[ind+1])-1 and id :
            print(id)
    except IndexError:
            print("out of", id)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to explain the logic better. How are `list1`, `list2`, and `list3` generated? Are you just grouping the original list into chunks of 3?

Comment: "And then compare each of them and only leave items which are equal like that..." This part I'm having trouble understanding what you are trying to do. Could you please explain further? The code you wrote as an example doesn't make sense and I'm trying to understand how you get `final = [18,19,28,29,38,39]` from the previous lists. Oh I think I see, you only want items that are 10 away from the previous / next list.

Comment: It seems like you're finding the last digits that exist in all the ranges of 10, and then returning all those numbers. Is that right?

Comment: So just to put this all together. You want to take a list of numbers, split it into groups of 3, then filter the lists so they only contain entries that are 10 away from an entry in another list. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Maybe not always I have 3 groups and 9 items , but what I will have is list with numbers where they are 10 away from each other. If there are numbers like that I have to save them in the new list.

Comment: So you just want to generate a new list that contains only numbers that are 10 away from another number in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to take a list as input and generate a new list that only contains elements of the original that are 10 away from another element in the original.

```py
my_list = [18, 19, 20, 27, 28, 29, 38, 39, 40]
new_list = list(filter(lambda x: x + 10 in my_list or x - 10 in my_list, my_list))
```

Here is a simple way to do just that using python's `filter` method.

Results:

```
[18, 19, 28, 29, 38, 39]
```

Comment: Thank you that's working. I will accept this answer.  For example now I checked ```my_list = [1, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 24, 25, 26, 28, 34, 40]``` , and got this result ```[14, 15, 16, 18, 24, 25, 26, 28, 34]```. For now what I want t achieve is to remove 18,28,and 34 because they are not in a row (I mean +1) . I know that this is different question already but can you help or just give me some hints? Thank you.

Comment: With this I have achieved . ```new_list2 = list(filter(lambda x: x + 1 in new_list or x - 1 in new_list, new_list))```. Тhank you and sorry for bothering.

Comment: You are welcome! I'm glad you were able to take this solution and customize it to meet your needs.