# What is Python list(), filter(), lambda equivalent to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, list, filter, lambda

This is [script in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73832522/how-to-compare-items-in-list). I want to achieve the same goal with Javascript. So the script is that

```
my_list = [18, 19, 20, 27, 28, 29, 38, 39, 40]

new_list = list(filter(lambda x: x + 10 in my_list or x - 10 in my_list, my_list))
```

What is equivalent of list(), filter(), lambda in this situation to convert Python to Javasript ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?

Comment: Python's `list()` is a constructor for single dimensional arrays (lists). In javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array

Comment: Python's `lambda` functions are, basically, small anonymous functions. In javascript: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-anonymous-functions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be converted to JavaScript using `Array.filter()` and `Array.includes()`.

```js
const my_list = [18, 19, 20, 27, 28, 29, 38, 39, 40]

const new_list = my_list.filter(x => my_list.includes(x+10) || my_list.includes(x-10))

console.log(new_list)
```